# How to convert a pandas dataframe sorted by x,y,z coordinates into a list of numpy arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe shown as:

```
    x y z t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 ...
c1  1 2 3 15 98 36 45 24
c2  2 ...
c3  3 ...
c4  4 ... 
c5  5 ...
c6  6 ...
.
.
.
```

Where essentially each row is a different coordinate, and each column is a point in a time-series, and each entry (c_i, t_j) is some measure. What I want to be able to do is put this into a sort of 4D Tensor (I hope this is the right terminology) where the dimensions are (x,y,z,t) so each entry is a 3D numpy ndarray with each term as the corresponding (c,t) measure.

Here's what I currently have:

```
tensor = []    

for i in range(len(list(df.columns)) - 3):
    tensor.append(np.zeros((max_x - min_x + 1, max_y - min_y + 1, max_z - min_z + 1)))
    for j in range(len(df["x"])):
        tensor[i][df["x"][j] - min_x][df["y"][j] - min_y][df["z"][j] - min_z] = df.iloc[:, i + 3][j]
```

Then I can simply convert the tensor into the requisite object needed. Currently, my dataset is 93164 x 13455 so I've estimated this to take about 32 hours. If this is the best way to do it, then I'll just deal with the wait, but I'd love to know if someone could come up with a faster way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I have understood you correctly, instead of having something like this:

```
x1 y1 z1 t1 t2 t3
```

Do you want something like this?

```
x1 y1 z1 t1

x1 y1 z1 t2

x1 y1 z1 t3
```

I think there is more than one way to do this, but here is one using the melt functionality in Pandas. Let's say you have a data frame (like the one below),  and you need to move the variables in t2 to t1 or to say it differently, you want to merge t1 and t2.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20]], columns=['x','y','t1','t2'])

    x   y  t1  t2
0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8
2   9  10  11  12
3  13  14  15  16
4  17  18  19  20
```

To do what I believe you said you wanted, you can do the following, with

```
f_df = df.melt(id_vars=['x','y'], value_vars = ['t1','t2'], value_name='t').drop('variable', axis=1).sort_values('x')
```

With now f_df:

```
    x   y   t
0   1   2   3
5   1   2   4
1   5   6   7
6   5   6   8
2   9  10  11
7   9  10  12
3  13  14  15
8  13  14  16
4  17  18  19
9  17  18  20
```

From here, you can simply transform this into a numpy array

Comment: Yes! This is perfect. Thank you so much.